# How to access inherited values

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a method with an exception variable as a parameter. This exception can sometimes inherit other values from custom exceptions, apart from its default values, and I was wondering how I could access these custom values without casting into custom exception object or verifying the `HResult` (this will always be the same due to how the method's arguments).

For example, in some cases the exception object can inherit a list, but I can't access this list. For this method to return the right value I must first find a way to identify the exception and by accessing the inherited values, I'll be able to.

This is what I've tried so far:

-Exception handling method-

```
private string ExceptionHandler(Exception ex)
{
    var customExceptionMessages = string.Empty;

    //I want to avoid this
    var customException = ex as CustomException;

    if (customException != null)
    {
        //Build custom exception message
        foreach (var v in customException.CustomViolations)
        {
            customExceptionMessages += v.ErrorMessage + "<br />";
        }

        return customExceptionMessages;
    }

    else
        return ex.Message;
}
```

-Example of usage-

```
ExceptionHandler(customEx);
```

After debugging, I noticed that before `ExceptionHandler` runs, `customEx`  has its user defined values. After `ExceptionHandler` starts running, `ex` inherits the default values of an exception plus the custom ones. I can't just say `ex.CustomViolations` cause this exists only on run time.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid casting using `as`? Also, if you just want to do some logic based on the type of Exception, you can write `if(ex is CustomException)`. But inside that `if` block you'd still have to cast `ex` to access it's class-specific properties and methods.

Comment: just a nitpick:  Typically, when we talk about `inherited` members of a class, we refer to the members that were already present in the base class, so `ex.Message` would be considered an inherited member.  the custom messages would not be.

Comment: Because I'll have to do this for every custom exception and I have a few. I'd prefer having a switch were I could case and check `ex` has a list with content then do this if it doesn't do this and so forth.

Comment: @SamIam snap, I knew. After a few minutes of trying to formulate this question correctly, I guess I forgot. I'll fix my typos.

Comment: @JoséCorretjer-Gómez then you can make an intermediate Exception class that has a virtual method such as `GetCustomExceptionMessages()`, and then in all of your custom messages, just override that method.

Comment: I was considering the method's argument as base, maybe that brought a bit of confusion. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you achieve this kind of thing using the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). However, here you can't modify `Exception`'s source code. Fortunately, in C# you have the [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword which allows you to do this:

```
private string ExceptionHandler(ConcreteException1 ex)
//...
private string ExceptionHandler(ConcreteException2 ex)
//...
private string ExceptionHandler(Exception ex) // default

x.ExceptionHanlder((dynamic)ex); // will call an appropriate overload
```

Of course, under the hood it does the type check internally, but the solution is scalable - the only thing you need is to add another overload for each new exception type.

---

Another approach in such cases when you don't have/don't want the `dynamic` type is to use a dictionary of concrete handlers for each exception:

```
Dictionary<Type, ExceptionHandler> handlers = ...

handlers[ex.GetType()].Handle(ex);
```

<sup>(in this example, I've changed `ExceptionHandler` to be a class name, and use `Handle` for the method name - that is the preferred, less confusing way to name methods and types ;) )</sup>

You can also involve some generic method magic to avoid casting inside the `Handle` method, but even without this, you don't have to check for invalid casts.

Comment: Why is dynamic required in the first example? shouldnt the overloads work fine without the cast!

Comment: @learnerplates No. The member overload mechanism works at compile time, so the last overload would have been chosen always, regardless of the actual type of `ex` (statically, `ex` is a reference of the `Exception` type). Only the `dynamic` keyword makes this possible at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Override the property `Message` inside your custom exception classes and build the desired message string inside the property getter. With that done you can simply return `ex.Message` and won't have to bother about the exception type.

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
     public override string Message
     {
         get
         {
             return <build message here>;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I think I can play around with this. The problem is that each user define exception can have multiple messages. For example, `CustomException`'s msg, in some cases can be "This is a message" and in others can be "I like ham".

Comment: Wait... I got something

Comment: If you can't determine the correct message inside the getter, how would you determine it outside in your exception handler method?

Comment: To clarify: You can do anything inside the getter (not only return a value). You can access other members of your exception class, do some crazy math or whatever. You can even move an enormous switch-case-block inside it or call some methods that will do the work.

Comment: `customException.CustomViolations` this list has a set of messages. Each index has a message. I build the final message by concatenating them. This list is built when a set of validations fails, after that goes to catch with customException

Comment: And why you can't do this inside the `Message` getter? You can provide the needed values through the class constructor when throwing the exception: `throw new CustomException(listOfViolations);`, store these values inside private class members and concat them inside the getter.

Comment: Even though this was a very good suggestion, with @BartoszKP suggestions I was able to cook up a plate full of logic and managed to solve it. Dynamic was the key for my switch case.

Comment: Yeah but I think it's bad design to build some custom handle method around it while the exception class offers a good solution for you. The `Message` property isn't virtual for no reason. You should build the message inside the exception class and not somewhere outside. Considering that you just create the message I don't even get why you would do this outside of the class. What happens if someone wants to use your exception class and doesn't have the handler method? He'll be screwed.